# How to make an activity scroll to a certain point?

Tags: android, scroll

Is it possible to have an activity scroll down to a certain  point when a button is clicked?

I want my activity to behave just like an anchor in a web page.

I have two buttons at the top of the activity, followed by lengthy text aboout each of the buttons.  When I click on the button at the top I want the page to scroll down beginning of that button's description.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a TextView to display your text, you use the built in scrolling function `myTextView.scrollTo(x,y)`. Put it inside your buttons' onClicks and you should be good to go!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

Answer (score 1):

So your outer layout is a scroll view?

You can call

`View.requestFocus()`

Obviously, the view has to be focusable.

The problem with scrollTo(x,y) mentioned above is most likely that you don't know x, y.